# How to install MySQL 5.5 on a Solaris 11 SPARC machine

Tags: mysql, solaris, sparc, mysql-5.5

I had MySQL 5.1 up and running on my SPARC Solaris 11 Sun Fire T2000.
The software I want to use needs MySQL 5.5.
I uninstalled the mysql-51 package and installed the mysql-55 package.
When I try to run mysql I get the error:

root:~# mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found

Did I not install the correct package?
Is there a viable 5.5 MySQL version for SPARC ?

Any tip on installing :)

Thanks

Comment: This is not on topic for stack overflow, so expect downvotes, negative comments and probably not any answer. Try on Server Fault where it would be more appropriate... also post the actual commands you ran to install / uninstall when you post again, I don't think it is possible for anyone to guess what went wrong from the information you're giving...

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/mysql/5.5/bin
```

Add it to your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.